How do I solve procmail not writing to $HOME/Maildir
I've searched the web all day for a solution to not being able to have procmail write to a users $HOME/Maildir directory. This includes searching on Virtualmin as I use Virtualmin to manage my server which is Ubuntu 20.04. My procmailrc is:
LOGFILE=/var/log/procmail.log
TRAP=/etc/webmin/virtual-server/procmail-logger.pl
:0wi
VIRTUALMIN=|/etc/webmin/virtual-server/lookup-domain.pl --exitcode 73 $LOGNAME
EXITCODE=$?
:0
* ?/bin/test "$EXITCODE" = "73"
/dev/null
EXITCODE=0
:0
* ?/bin/test "$VIRTUALMIN" != ""
{
INCLUDERC=/etc/webmin/virtual-server/procmail/$VIRTUALMIN
}
ORGMAIL=$HOME/Maildir/
DEFAULT=$HOME/Maildir/
DROPPRIVS=yes

The procmail error log shows multiple entries such as
Insecure dependency in exec while running with -T switch at /etc/webmin/virtual-
server/lookup-domain.pl line 19.
procmail: Program failure (255) of "/etc/webmin/virtual-server/lookup-domain.pl"
procmail: Unable to treat as directory "/home/xxxx/Maildir"
procmail: Lock failure on "/home/mike/Maildir.lock"
procmail: Error while writing to "/home/xxxx/Maildir"

Line 19 of lookup-domain.pl is
 exec("$root/virtual-server/lookup-domain.pl", @ARGV) || die "Failed to run $>
20

The format of the users $HOME directory is /home/example/homes/xxxx/Maildir as created by Virtualmin and the procmailrc file is also generated by Virtualmin.
From the log its clear that procmail is not interpreting $HOME/Maildir correctly.
Any advice greatly appreciated, of course.

Often mail delivery subsystems they expect a Maildir to be a path defined by a trailing /  ; your error might suggest that your user lookup returns a path without that trailing slash I.e. "/home/xxxx/Maildir" should be "/home/xxxx/Maildir/" for it to be considered a Maildir

This is really a Perl error. It basically means that something in the script you call is using unsafe constructs.
In more detail, -T or "taint mode" activates an analysis of where the values of variables come from, with the goal of preventing user-supplied, unsafe values from being passed to a system call or etc. Imagine if the value you passed to exec might contain system("rm -rf /");
I'm guessing it dislikes the unprocessed @ARGV, but there could be additional problems with how $root gets its value, or other parts of the script which you aren't showing.
You are using @ARGV to pass in options and $LOGNAME (which strictly speaking should be in double quotes here). Perhaps you could verify that these values only contain dashes and alphabetics before passing them on; but without access to the full script, this is of course entirely speculative, and I'll just defer you to the Perl documentation for how to properly solve taint errors.
The errors after that might simply be fallout from the first error, though they seem to indicate a second problem. You cannot deliver to /home/mike/Maildir because this location doesn't exist, or isn't a directory.
In order for this to work, obviously /home/mike needs to exist (and Procmail needs to have write access; though judging from the DROPPRIVS, this is running as root, so probably in /etc/procmailrc, not a personal recipe file) and Maildir needs to exist as a directory within that, and Procmail needs to be able to (create, if necessary, and) write to the new, tmp, and cur subdirectories which are required by the Maildir spec. (Concretely, Procmail always writes new messages to new.)
I can still imagine that this error is simply fallout from not being prepared that the Perl script could fail, and that you might be able to ignore these problems when you have fixed the current failure. Properly speaking, of course, you should still be prepared for additional robustness problems in that script, and make sure Procmail can cope correctly if it fails ... though "correctly" might simply be to refuse to deliver the message; setting EXITCODE to a nonzero value basically does that already, and will cause your MTA to respond with a "delivery failed" bounce message. You should do that instead of delivering to /dev/null and pretending everything is fine. The usual idiom is something like
:0
* ! EXITCODE ?? ^^0^^
( HOST= }

Setting HOST to a null value signals to Procmail to abort processing the current recipe file here and now (though if you are in an INCLUDERC= it will return to the calling recipe file, not abort everything).
Actually, you could replace the lines between EXITCODE=$? and ORGMAIL=$HOME/Maildir/ with
:0
*   EXITCODE   ?? ^0$
* ! VIRTUALMIN ?? ^$
{ INCLUDERC=/etc/webmin/virtual-server/procmail/$VIRTUALMIN }
:0E
{ EXITCODE=73 HOST= }

This also avoids the pesky and expensive external calls to test for things which Procmail can perfectly well do natively.

I could have created some confusion by inconsistent use of substituting xxxx for mike. The  essence is that /home/mike/Maildir does not exist but /home/example/mike/homes does. The script is interpreting $HOME as /home/mike/ when it should interpret it as /home/example/mike/homes. As both the procmailrc and lookup-domain.pl are provided by  Virtualmin I don't know how  to achieve the correct interpretation of $HOME

I can't help with that part; I'm guessing they were not prepared for the script to be invoked as root which activates taint mode; but I am not at all familiar with Virtualmin or its goals or promises, so probably bring this up with them. The immediate problem is that the script refuses to run so of course it doesn't provide the mapping you need and expect. If it's not a complex script it should not be hard to fix or replace.

https://github.com/virtualmin/virtualmin-gpl/blob/03debb9289ee363488a56ded09fe4ff673f86ac0/lookup-domain.pl#L23 doesn't have this exec line but it was last changed many years ago. What version exactly are you running?

I tried substituting the github version but it was no better:

As in, you still got the same error, or as in it also didn't work, but for other reasons? Again, which precise version are you running, how did you install it, from where?
